# Treeview control (comctl32 / VB5-era) missing icons & captions?

Tags: windows-8, vb6, treeview

VB6 app works fine on Windows 8 with one exception:

Display form with treeview.  Displays correctly.
Click button which displays another form used for entry.
When the new form is dismissed (and a new node added to the treeview) all nodes' pictures and  are invisible.  The +/- signs display, but not the pictures and captions.

If the form is closed and then re-opened, all nodes are properly displayed until another form is opened.

The two forms involved are both MDI child forms.

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming it's not making a change to the control or ImageList, it's not a general Windows 8 issue. My treeview works fine. Can you confirm which treeview control you're actually using? The VB6 common control, or the VB5 common controls? If the latter, does your application have a manifest to get the v6/themed controls?

Comment: Hi Deanna.  You may have just resolved the problem.  I didn't realize that I was using comctl32.ocx (VB5 common controls) instead of mscomctl.ocx (VB6 common controls) in this project.  I'll be able to test this out later today - Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue. It turned out to be that we still used the VB5 TreeView. The VB6 one works fine.It only does not have a style for when it is disabled.

Comment: Note that the VB6 version of the control is a copy of the real treeview and so won't have themeing applied to it. Using the XP manifest may also have resolved/worked around it.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem on a client machine. Unfortunately I didn't have the luxury of rebuilding using VB6 (mscomctl.ocx) controls, which according to the previous comment should work.

However it turns out that if you disable the "Touchscreen keyboard and handwriting panel" service in Windows 8 the comctl32.ocx TreeView control will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC from prior experience, while the treeview in COMCTL32 (from VB5) has this issue, updating the program to use the VB6-era MSCOMCTL32 treeview should fix it. I don't think we ever found any other fix for the root problem, assuming you can't disable the touch services.

I believe the two treeviews are very similar and this upgrade shouldn't be difficult.

I don't recall if any other common controls had the same issue.