# TreeView control (comctl32.ocx) does not load with touch screen services

Tags: vb6, treeview, windows-services

I am facing an issue in loading a TreeView control (comctl32.ocx) in "Windows Server 2012 R2" machine. The TreeView style used is `tvwpictureText`.

When I googled for a solution. I have found the solution saying: if you disable the service "Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service". the control will load.

The TreeView control(comctl32.ocx) is not loading properly when service is enabled:

[image]

If I disable this service and restart the machine then the TreeView control (comctl32.ocx) loads properly:

[image]

If I use mscomctl.ocx, TreeView also loads properly irrespective of the service being enabled/disable in Windows Server 2012 R2 machine. But I can't use mscomctl.ocx for development because all projects are built with comctl32.ocx.

Here I want to know why this service is causing the problem to load the TreeView control of comctl32.ocx. Is there any alternative for this issue?

Comment: As far as I am aware, comctl32.ocx has compatibility problems with touch screens. It may well be that specific service which affects it, but I think the problem was in comctl32 itself. IIRC the update from comctl32 to mscomctl32 was not very hard. Also, you can use both at once so perhaps you can only upgrade the controls which actually are failing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Treeview control (comctl32 / VB5-era) missing icons & captions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879964/treeview-control-comctl32-vb5-era-missing-icons-captions)

Comment: Works fine in Windows 10 without disabling the service.  Probably time to get off those Win 8.x OSs including the server SKUs of same.

Answer (score 1):

If you could afford not using the images on the TreeView, it should work properly if you change the "Style" property to 0 (tvwTextOnly). This solution worked on my application.